# C++ compiler error involving private inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, compiler-errors, private-inheritance

Could someone please explain the following compiler error to me:

```
struct B
{
};

template <typename T>
struct A : private T
{
};

struct C : public A<B>            
{                                                                             
    C(A<B>);   // ERROR HERE
};
```

The error at the indicated line is:

```
test.cpp:2:1: error: 'struct B B::B' is inaccessible
test.cpp:12:7: error: within this context
```

What exactly is inaccessible, and why?

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, What does C(A<B>) mean here?

Comment: @fizzbuzz: Constructor taking an `A<B>` by value.

Comment: @Xeo, oh yes,  A<B> is just a type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `A< ::B>` or `A<struct B>`.

Inside of `C`, unqualified references to `B` will pick up the so-called *injected-class-name*, it is brought in through the base class `A`. Since `A` inherits privately from `B`, the *injected-class-name* follows suit and will also be private, hence be inaccessible to `C`.

Another day, another language quirk...

Comment: Good question. My answer looked like "Try `A< ::B>`. Why? Beats me..." at first. Now, the error message refers to `B::B`, the constructor, so that was about the only option. And no, I don't know why it tries to select a member function inside a template argument list...

Comment: So, is this parsing quirk intentional, a compiler bug (unlikely since both GCC and Comeau give this error), or under/mis-specification of parsing in the standard?

Comment: All three MSVC, GCC and Clang spew this error, so it must be something in the spec.. I just asked on the llvm IRC channel, will report back.

Comment: I also opened up a [follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9223441/500104).

Answer (score 4):

The problem is name shielding of struct B .
Check it out:

```
struct B{};

struct X{};

template <class T>
struct A : private T
{};

struct C : public A<B>
{
    C(){
          A<X> t1;     // WORKS
 //       A<B> t2;     // WRONG
          A< ::B> t3;  // WORKS
    }   
};

int main () {
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are making `A` `private`ly inherit from `B` when you do `A<B>`, and that means that `B::B` is `private` so you can't construct a `C`.

Comment: Wrong, `A<B>` has to construct the `B` base subobject, and it's accessible there.

Comment: What is `B::B`? B's implicitly declared default constructor?

Comment: @HighCommander `B::B` is the implicitly declared default constructor that is made `private` in `A<B>`.