# Why does the compiler select the base class constructor inside the template argument list?

Tags: c++, templates, scope, c++11, base-class

Follow-up question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9223153/500104).

Basically, in the following code, why does the compiler think that the `B` inside `A<B>` in `C`s constructor refer to the (inaccessible) constructor of the `B` base class?

```
struct B{};

template <typename T>
struct A : private T{};

struct C : public A<B>{                                                                             
    C(A<B>);   // ERROR HERE
};
```

[Live example on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/qgVQ5) Output:

> prog.cpp:1:9: error: 'struct B B::B' is inaccessible
>   prog.cpp:7:7: error: within this context

Note that the same error pops up if you change the constructor argument to `A<B*>`, `A<B&>` or even `A<const B>`. Also note that three of MSVC10, GCC 4.7 and Clang 3.1 ToT will error out, so it must be something in the C++ spec. **What is it?**

Comment: I don't know why you created the exact same topic! You could have edited that topic to make that a better one.

Comment: @Nawaz: It's fundamentally a different question. I ask "why", the other question asks "what to do".

Comment: Man, I've been bitten by this more than once with `class A : private NotCopyable { class B : private NotCopyable {} };`.  I guess it looks up symbols in the class scope before looking at the global scope.

Comment: @Xeo: That is why I said *you could have edited that topic to make that a better one.*

Comment: @AndréCaron: That particular example compiles fine.

Comment: @Xeo: yes indeed since `B` has access to `A`'s privates.  I can't remember what the exact code sample was, but it was the same problem where using the type name of a private base class was messing up things.

Comment: @Xeo: just remembered.  Something along the lines of `A` inherits `NotCopyable`, `B` inherits `A` and `B::C` inherits `NotCopyable`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The standard allows injected class names to be less accessible than the original names. This is even mentioned in a note in §11.1/5, together with an example:

> [ *Note:* In a derived class, the lookup of a base class name will
> find the injected-class-name instead of the name of the base class in
> the scope in which it was declared. The injected-class-name might be
> less accessible than the name of the base class in the scope in which
> it was declared. *—end note* ]
>
> [ *Example*:
>
> ```
> class A { };
> class B : private A { };
> class C : public B {
>   A *p; // error: injected-class-name A is inaccessible
>   ::A *q; // OK
> };
> ```
>
> —*end example* ]

Accessing `A` unqualified uses the injected name, which is not accessible because it comes from private inheritance. Accessing `A` qualified uses the declared name, which is accessible in the global scope.