# Interface is inaccessible?

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ inheritance - inaccessible base?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847100/c-inheritance-inaccessible-base)
>   [Why does the compiler select the base class constructor inside the template argument list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9223441/why-does-the-compiler-select-the-base-class-constructor-inside-the-template-argu)

```
class InterfaceA
{
public:
  virtual void f () = 0;
};

class A :
  private InterfaceA
{
public:
  void f () {}

};

class B :
  public A
{
private:
  /*::*/InterfaceA * m_a; // Adding "::" makes it work
};
```

GCC and VS2008 say `‘class InterfaceA’ is inaccessible`. If i declare `m_a` with explicit global scope everything compiles fine.

upd: `m_a` is a `pointer`, not an object itself. In fact the question why can't i declare `a pointer` and why adding "::" solves this problem?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate - it asks about accessing the base class, not it's (inherited) members. But because the question is closed, I will answer here: Without the ::, you see the InterfaceA class with the inherited visibility (private, because of A), so you can't see anything inside of it, except public static functions. With the :: you are accessing it from the global namespace, and see it as if you were accessing it from the main function - the fact that it's inherited is ignored.